# Probability of sequence

Tags: probability-theory

The question is as follow: Let $(X_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence of Random variable that is independent with the probability

$P(X_{n}=1)=1-P(X_{n}=0)=\frac{1}{n}$

Show that $P\left( \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }\liminf{ X }_{ n }=0 \right) =1$

I tried to use the Borel-Cantelli Theorem to prove this, however I obtain that

$P\left( \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }\liminf{ X }_{ n }=0 \right) =0$

${ F }_{ n }:=\left\{ { X }_{ n }=0 \right\} $

$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ P\left( { F }_{ n }^{ C } \right)  } =\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ 1-P\left( X_{ n }=0 \right)  } =\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n }  } =\infty$

By Borel-Cantelli, we know that $P\left( { \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }\limsup  }{ F }_{ n }^{ C } \right) =1$

Since ${ \left( { \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \liminf }  }{ F }_{ n } \right)  }^{ C }=\left( { \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }{\limsup}  }\quad { F }_{ n }^{ C } \right) $,

(ie) $P\left( { \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \liminf }  }\quad { F }_{ n } \right) =1-P\left( { \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \limsup }  }\quad { F }_{ n }^{ C } \right)$,

I obtain that $P\left( { \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \liminf }  }\quad { X }_{ n }=0 \right) =0$

Since this is the opposite of what I want to prove and the statement is said to be true, I can't see where I went wrong in my argument.

Comment: You may be interested in the commands `\limsup` and `\liminf` which render respectively as $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake in the last line of your argument
$$ \liminf_{n \to \infty} F_n = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \lbrace X_n = 0 \rbrace \neq \lbrace \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n = 0 \rbrace$$

The event $\liminf F_n$ is the event that eventually $F_n$ will be true. That is from some moment $k$ for every $n > k$, $F_n$ will happen. In this case this is equivalent to say that the sequence will be constant and equal to zero.

Independent Borel-Cantelli will assure you that both $\limsup F_n$ and $\limsup F_n^c$ will be true, since both probability series diverge. Remember that the interpretation of limsups of events is that the event will happen infinitely often (i.o). That means that both $\lbrace X_n = 0 \rbrace$ and $\lbrace X_n = 1 \rbrace$ will happen i.o. which implies that almost surely $\liminf X_n = 0$ and $\limsup X_n = 1$

Comment: how does both {X_n=0} and {X_n=1} will happen i.o implies almost surely lim inf X_n=0 and lim sup X_n=1?

Comment: We have for example $\lbrace X_n = 1 \; \text{i.o.} \rbrace$. Remember that the limsup of a sequence of reals is the largest accumulation point. Since $1$ appears an infinite number of times and the sequence can take only the values $0$ or $1$, then necessarily the largest point of accumulation is $1$. 

The same can be said of the liminf, considering that this is the smallest accumulation point of a sequence.

Comment: In your example the events that have probability zero are $\lbrace X_n = 0 \; \text{eventually} \rbrace$ and $\lbrace X_n = 1 \; \text{eventually} \rbrace$. When one of these events happens the sequence converges since it means that they are constant from some point on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, for $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables $(X_n)$,

> $$[\liminf X_n=0]=\limsup\ [X_n=0]$$
>   $$[\limsup X_n=0]=\liminf\ [X_n=0]\quad(=[\lim X_n=0])$$

The event $A=[\liminf X_n=0]$ is $A=\limsup A_n$ with $A_n=[X_n=0]$. Now, $\limsup A_n=\bigcap\limits_nB_n$ with $B_n=\bigcup\limits_{k\geqslant n}A_k$. For every $n$ and $k\geqslant n$, $A_k\subseteq B_n$ and $P[A_k]=1-1/k$ hence $P[B_n]\geqslant1-1/k$ hence $P[B_n]=1$. Thus, $P[A]=1$.

This does not use the independence property, only the hypothesis that $P[X_n\ne0]\to0$.

---

Regarding your proof, note that you are asked to compute the probability of $[X=0]$ with $X=\liminf X_n$, and that you compute the probability of $\liminf [X_n=0]$ instead. In other words, your problem is that you assumed (wrongly) that the events
$[\liminf X_n=0]$ and $\liminf [X_n=0]$ coincide.

Comment: The property where {lim inf X_n=0} = lim sup {X_n=0}. Is this a general property of the \limsup and \liminf? I don't quite get this part.

Comment: The property is specific to random variables with values in $\{0\}\cup S$ with $S\subseteq[x,+\infty)$ for some $x\gt0$. Let me suggest that you begin by wondering what it means for a deterministic sequence $(x_n)$ with values in $\{0\}\cup S$ that $\liminf x_n=0$.

Comment: Something like $x_{n}=1- \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: ??? Do you really think $\liminf(1-\frac1n)=0$?

Comment: oh... sorry... I mean $x_{n}= \frac{1}{n}$. So $\liminf x_{n}=0$

Comment: OK, obviously you did not even pay attention to my comment. Why should I help any further?

Comment: Hi Did, I'm so sorry about it. I'm really very slow when it comes to understanding new ideas. So I need a sequence that takes in the value 0 also and it needs to be a positive valued sequence with $\liminf x_{n}=0$ right?

Answer (score 0):

Note $1-P(X_n=0)=1/n$ implies $P(X_n=0)=1-1/n$ or $P(X_n=0)=(n-1)/n$ and apply Borel-Cantelli.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I know about the probability of X_n=0. But if I sum along all n, the infinite sum of 1-1/n is infinity. This implies that P(lim sup X_n=0)=1. How do I get P(lim inf X_n=0) from this? @Trurl

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain about the statement of the problem? I can't see what is wrong with your proof,  and using [Borel 0-1 law](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_du_z%C3%A9ro-un_de_Borel) (in French, but this is basically a statement similar to, while slightly easier to use than, the Borel-Canetelli lemma; see also Pro. 2.2 from [these lecture notes](http://www.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring07/sta205/lec/indep.pdf) with $F_n$ (independent events, with $\mathbb{P} F_n=\frac{1}{n}$), one also gets that
$$
 \mathbb{P}\{ \limsup_{n\to+\infty} F_n \} = 1
$$
since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} F_n = +\infty$. In other terms, infinitely many of the $F_n$'s occur, i.e. $X_n=0$ for infinitely many values of $n$. But then, one cannot have $X_n=0$ ultimately (that is, $\forall n \geq N$ for some $N$) w.p. $1$, which is the result you are apparently asked to show.

**Edit**: what I wrote is wrong (from the beginning), in the sense that it is not the right quantity that is considered. See Did's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Fatou's lemma instead of Borel-Cantelli can prove to be useful. Fatou's lemma is applicable to $\{X_n\}$ since they are non-negative. By Fatou's lemma, \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\ &\mathbb{E}(\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n)\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n)=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0\\
\ & \Rightarrow P(\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n=1)\leq 0\\
\ & \Rightarrow P(\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n=0)=1\hspace{0.6cm} \Box
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Otherwise, if you really want to use BC lemma then the answer given by @Did is useful.